# Can the intersection of a sequence of nested open intervals be nonempty and have finite cardinality?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Clearly you can create a sequence of nested open intervals whos intersection is an interval, but what about an intersection with a single finite element? My main question is whether $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n $,  where $I_n= (b - 1/n , b + 1/n)$, would have $b$ as an element or not? Also why this is or isn't the case?

Comment: Given that you've been around for a while, you should know to use MathJax formatting in your questions.

Comment: $b$ is in each $I_n$, so it's in their intersection.

Comment: @Aweygan I haven't learned it and I don't use any math software which I'm assuming is how a lot of people pick up this stuff. I don't think I ask questions all that frequently either.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well I improved it with what you posted. Might take some searching before I can find ways to go even further into the mathjax

Comment: You should put "n=1" within dollar signs, and \infty is used for "infinity". @Hockeyfan19

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  ah thanks, it's looking a little nicer now

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Okay I think it's been fully Jax'ed now

Answer (score 3):

An infinite intersection of open sets may not be open. Proof that $b \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$:

$b - \frac{1}{n} < b < b + \frac{1}{n},\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$b \in I_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$b \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Can you prove that $b$ is the only element in $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$?

Comment: You are definitely right if n is an element of $\Bbb{N}$ , but what about when $n = \infty $? That is what has confused me the most about this. I'll have to think about if I can prove that or not.

Comment: "For all n in N" is equivalent to "n from 1 to infinity". Infinity is not an element of N, in this context it means that there is no upper bound.